# How to troubleshoot - BUG in libdispatch?

Tags: redhat, fedora

I've a service on my linux server that I need start, however when starting the service i get the follwing error code after running `systemctl status [SERVICE]`

**Error:**

```
$ systemctl status [SERVICE]
BUG in libdispatch 0xfffffffffffff
BUG in libdispatch 0xa14
```

I'm fairly new to linux and I wonder where I should start, I have not found anything in the `/var/log/messages` which reflects the overall OS.

One of my question is:
Is this an application or is it an OS issue?